# Is there a better way to initialize a Hastable in .NET without using Add method?

Tags: c#

I am currently initializing a Hashtable in the following way:

```
Hashtable filter = new Hashtable();
filter.Add("building", "A-51");
filter.Add("apartment", "210");
```

I am looking for a nicer way to do this.

I tried something like

```
Hashtable filter2 = new Hashtable() {
    {"building", "A-51"},
    {"apartment", "210"}
};
```

However the above code does not compile.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The exact code you posted:

```
        Hashtable filter2 = new Hashtable()
        {
            {"building", "A-51"},
            {"apartment", "210"}
        };
```

Compiles perfectly in C# 3. Given you reported compilation problems, I'm guessing you are using C# 2? In this case you can at least do this:

```
        Hashtable filter2 = new Hashtable();
        filter2["building"] = "A-51";
        filter2["apartment"] = "210";
```

Answer (score 9):

In C# 3 it should compile fine like this:

```
Hashtable table = new Hashtable {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
```

Comment: For object initializers, the Constructor parens are optional?

Comment: if you have en empty ctor, ya

Answer (score 0):

(Not a C# expert)

This is syntactic sugar, and if it's syntactic sugar I'd want to have the mapping (in a Hashtable) nice and obvious:

```
Hashtable filter2 = new Hashtable() { "building" => "A-51", "apartment" => "210"};
```

However I don't see a real need for this, there isn't much wrong with just having to call add after initialisation.

(I've known people to hack around with the Java compiler to achieve similar things in the past for Java (which caused major issues moving to Java 5 a few years later), I expect this isn't an option for C# though!)

Comment: There is aneed if you need to add it inline:

someclass.AddTable(new HashTable { { 1, "A" }, {2, "b"} } );

Answer (score 0):

I had no idea in C# 3.0 `Hashtable table = new Hashtable {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};` would compile.

Anyway, poor man's implementation:

Meh, you could extend the Hashtable class:

```
class MyHashTable : System.Collections.Hashtable    
{
    public MyHashTable(string [,] values)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (values.Length)/2; i++)
        {
            this.Add(values[i,0], values[i,1]);
        }
    }
}
```

And then from a Console App:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[,] initialize = { { "building", "A-51" }, { "apartment", "210" }, {"wow", "nerf Druids"}};



        MyHashTable myhashTable = new MyHashTable(initialize);
        Console.WriteLine(myhashTable["building"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(myhashTable["apartment"].ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(myhashTable["wow"].ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
}
```

will result in:
A-51
210
nerf Druids

this was done quick so it may bomb in certain situations but then again..

Comment: maybe object[,] ? because you can use any (immutable) object as Hashtable key, not just strings.

And btw, drus have seen enough nerfing :) Mages too ;) (disclaimer: not-so-unhappy mage :))

Answer (score -1):

I think the real question being asked may be about imaginable constructors such as:

HashTable ht = new HashTable(MyArray) ; // fill from array

HashTable ht = new HashTable(MyDataTable) ; // fill from datatable

AFAIK, the answer is "no", but you could write it yourself. I assume the reason that such methods are not in the library is that the Array or DataTable has to be properly formed. It's not such a big loss since any implementation of these methods would probably be using the Add method in a loop anyway.

Comment: Object initializers as the poster posted is part of the C# 3 language spec. The compiler takes the code and compiles it into Add calls. Pretty much any class that has an add method (implementing IEnumerable) can be initialized in this way.